# Scroll to element returning offset null

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get an element id from a select box, and then scroll to that element with:

```
// jump to services
$(function () {
    $("select.jump").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        console.log(selected);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + selected).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

`console.log(selected)` returns my id correctly, but I get offset is null.

It appears its a bracket and slash issue in my ID seletors.

Comment: Ok this works, but I think I get an error as I have a / in my selector.

Comment: If you have more information to add, put it in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Hard to help without HTML. And fiddle would help a lot too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you have brackets and slashes in your IDs.

Whether or not they are square brackets or ordinary brackets, **brackets have special meaning in jQuery selectors**. And including slashes, you should avoid them altogether in your HTML IDs. It's basically illegal IDs if you refer to the W3C spec.

Square brackets in jQuery selectors are **attribute-related**.

Ordinary brackets in jQuery selectors are **filter-related**.

See jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

And the most typical selectors are basically the same as **CSS selectors**, and should follow the same naming conventions as such: See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Here I quote from the above W3C link:

> identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Here is a demo to illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/tkx36/

While there is nothing essentially wrong with your script, a safety net would be nice:

```
// jump to services
$(function () {
    $("select.jump").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val(),
            $selected = $("#" + selected);

        if ($selected.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $selected.offset().top
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            // handle this in case element is not found
        }
    });
});
```